# GraphViz - How to have a subgraph be top-to-bottom when main graph is left-to-right?

Tags: r, graphviz, diagrammer

I have a graph in direction of LR

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  node [shape=box]
  x1;x2;x3;y1;y2;y3;y4;y5;y6;y7;y8;
  node [shape=oval]
  ind60;dem60;dem65;
  {x1,x2,x3} -> ind60 
  dem65->{y5,y6,y7,y8} 

  subgraph cluster_0{
  rankdir=TB 

  {y1,y2,y3,y4} -> dem60[constraint=false]

  }
  ind60->dem60 ind60->dem65 dem60->dem65
}
```

The result is as follows:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5tGD.png)

I want the subgraph in TB direction. How can I achieve this?

[subgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkUJX.png)

Comment: im sure im being dense here but your subgraph look top to bottom to me

Comment: TB = Top to Bottom, your cluster_0 subgraph has y1 at the TOP and y4 is at the BOTTOM. That is Top to Bottom direction. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I want the subgraph looks like as the image 'subgraph'. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation rankdir only works for graphs not for subgraphs.

You can workaround this by adding some scaffolding in form of invisible edges and nodes like this

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  node [shape=box]
  x1;x2;x3;y1;y2;y3;y4;y5;y6;y7;y8;
  node [shape=oval]
  ind60;dem60;dem65;
  {x1,x2,x3} -> ind60 
  dem65->{y5,y6,y7,y8} 

  subgraph cluster_0{

      y2a[shape=point color=none]
      y1->y2->y2a->y3->y4[color=none weight=1000]
      {y1 y2}->dem60
      {rank=same y2a->dem60[color=none]}
      {y3 y4}->dem60

  }
  {rank=same ya[shape=point color=none] x1 x2 x3}
  {rank=same yb[shape=point color=none] y5 y6 y7 y8}
  ya->y1[color=none] y4->yb[color=none]
  ind60->dem60 ind60->dem65 dem60->dem65
}
```

[image]